# Duplicate symbol error at linkage: Macro definition at play?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I defined a multi-line macro to be re-used throughout my project and I seem to get a linker error on the mangled name:

duplicate symbol __ZN3src9Utilities9findIndexEPNSt3__113basic_fstreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEERKNS1_12basic_stringIcS4_NS1_9allocatorIcEEEERKN5boost14char_separatorIcS4_E

My code that defines the macro is the following:

```
namespace QL = QuantLib;

namespace src
{
    #ifndef FILE_PARSE_LENGTH
        #define FILE_PARSE_LENGTH 1000
    #endif

    #define _RUNTIME_CALCULATION(timer, message) {\
                                        using namespace QL; \
                                        Real seconds = timer.elapsed();\
                                        auto hours = int(seconds/3600);\
                                        seconds -= hours * 3600;\
                                        auto minutes = int(seconds/60);\
                                        seconds -= minutes * 60;\
                                        std::cout << "\n" << message;\
                                        if (hours > 0)\
                                            std::cout << hours << " h ";\
                                        if (hours > 0 || minutes > 0)\
                                            std::cout << minutes << " m ";\
                                        std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(5) << seconds << " s\n" << std::endl;\
                                        std::cout << "=======================================================================================" \
                                        << std::endl; \
                                        }

    namespace Utilities
    {
        typedef boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char>> tokenizer;
        const boost::char_separator<char> char_sep{",\t <>\n\r"};

        int findIndex(std::fstream* file, const std::string& col, const boost::char_separator<char>& csep)
        {
            // blah blah blah....
        }
    }
}
```

and the Macro defined above (_RUNTIME_CALCULATION) is used throughout my project in other .cpp files as _RUNTIME_CALCULATION(timer, "blah blah blah...");

Anyone sees something I may be oblivious to here, as I have already wasted some time on this?

Many thanks,
Amine

Comment: No relationship to the (hair-rising) macro: this code apparently lives in a header, and you're defining `findIndex` as a non-`inline` function, hence the multiple definitions error.

Comment: In lining the function findIndex works! Thanks Quentin